# ASP.NET MVC ActionLink not selecting correct controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

***Question background:***

I'm trying to pass an variable - in this case an int 'productId' variable' in the url to a controller and action method specified in the ActionLink method.

***The issue:***

My routes are set as follows:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProductDetailHandler",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{productId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductDetail", productId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My 'ActionLink' in my 'Products.cshtml' view - which is returned by a controller called 'HomePageController' is set as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Product", "ProductDetail", new { productId = (ViewBag.data as List<LoginTest.Models.HomePageItem>).First().Id })
```

The controller that receives the passed 'productId' along with its action method is set as follows:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ProductDetail(int productId)
    {
        //logic

        return View();
    }
}
```

This is the issue, when looking at the URL it is shown to be redirecting to the 'HomePage' controller:

[image: ']

If someone could tell me why my ActionLink is ***not*** going to the ***Product*** controller that would be great.

***EDIT:***

This is the 'Homepage' view that I click a button to redirect me to '**product/productDetail/productId**'

[image]

My route now just features the 'Default example':

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The Action Link is now:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Product", "ProductDetail", "Product", new { id = (ViewBag.data as List<LoginTest.Models.HomePageItem>).First().Id })
```

The 'Product/ProductDetail' controller and action method now looks like:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ProductDetail(int id)
    {
        string hold;

        return View();
    }
}
```

This still is giving me the the incorrect URL, as shown, note the 'productId' is now showing as 'length'?

[image]

Comment: Do you have other routes in the route file? The default route of controller/action/id should have worked. You don't need custom routes that are basically the same. Also in you example, productid also should not have shown up in the querystring.

Comment: @Kirby I've added the entire contents of my RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Move your `ProductDetailHandler` route before the `Default` and change the url to `url: "Product/ProductDetail/{productId}", or just delete the route and change the method to `ProductDetail(int id)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your reply. I tried both of your suggestion and sadly the url still routes to 'homepage/productdetail/idValue'

Comment: Not sure what's going on here. Are you redirecting from login to a controller called home page? Are you maybe calling a different View in some action method which will not necessarily change the URL?

Comment: Your `@Html.ActionLink()` is not specifying the controller so it defauls to HomePage (it should be @Html.ActionLink("Product", "ProductDetail", "Product", ...) but you still need to reverse the order in the route table anyway

Comment: @kirby I'm redirecting from my homepage to a product page. The i'd of an item featured on the homepage is carried to the product page to display it.I've edited my question showing this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your reply again. I've edited my code - as shown in my edits on the question. The issue is still persisting though.

Comment: @user1352057, Sorry, I should have written it in full (the overload that has the controller name needs a parameter for html attributes) `@Html.ActionLink("Product", "ProductDetail", "Product", new { id = 1 }, null)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I got this to work now. I had to also set 'null' for the htmlAttributes on the ActionLink overload. You gave me the nearest answer though specifying I needed the 'controller\actionmethod\controller' so if you could set this as the answer i'll mark it correct.  edit: Just noticed you said about the 'null'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the link is on a page rendered by `HomePageController` the default is to use that controller in the route. You need to use the overload that accepts a controller name

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your link text", "ProductDetail", "Product", new { id = 1 }, null)
```

As a side note, your original route table would have created `/Product/ProductDetail?productId =1` with this overload because it matches the default route which is the first route in your table (the order of routes is important). In order to have `/Product/ProductDetail/1`, either reverse the order of the routes or just change the parameter of `ProductDetail` to `int id` rather than `int productId`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using an overload that has `controllerName` in it, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

When I remove `routeValues: null`, it uses a different overlaod which has routeValue as third paramater.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetailHandler",
    url: "Product/{action}/{productId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductDetail", productId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute
(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Not sure what you are trying to do with the Login controller. Maybe you can put log-in on your Home page or redirect the Home/Index to Login.

Also you can specify the default namespace if it doesn't find your controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductDetailHandler",
    url: "Product/{action}/{productId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductDetail", productId = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
);

routes.MapRoute
(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new string[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
);
```